# RAM analysis on Linux

Tags: linux, memory-management

I want to get the map of allocated memory in RAM running on Linux.

I am looking to find the utilization of memory at a given time as well as specifics of allocation in terms of user process and kernel modules and kernel itself.

Answer (score 2):

This is very very hard to get right because of shared memory, caching and on demand paging.

You can indeed use /proc/PID/maps as the previous answer stated to learn that glibc, as an example, occupies a certain range of virtual memory in a certain process but part of that is shared between all processes mapping that library (the code section), part isn't (the dynamic linker tables, for example). Part of this memory space might not be in RAM at all (paged to disk) anc opy on write semantics might mean that the memory picture at the next moment might be very different.

Add do that the sophisticated use Linux makes in caching (the page and buffer caches being the major ones) which part of which can be evicted at the kernel whim (cache IO buffers which are not dirty) but some cannot (e.g. tmpfs pages) and it gets really hairy really quickly.

In short - no one good answer to get a true view of what uses RAM and for what in a Linux system.   The best answer I know is pagemap and related tool. read all about it here: http://lwn.net/Articles/230975/

Answer (score 0):

You can find it out by checking ever process memory mapping

```
cat /proc/<PID>/maps
```

and for overall memory state

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

Comment: Here is an extract of /proc/<pid>/maps of a process, can you help me understand the parts amongst it. " 403fc000-403fd000 r-xp 000f6000 1f:05 234 /lib/libc-2.5.so " Looks to me like the first part represents the address where the data is mapped followed by access permissions others I am not able to relate.

Comment: The fields in each line are:
start-end perm offset major:minor inode image Take look at http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-1